# How to display database values one by one from firebase in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to build a tinder like app in react native. The potential matches are stored in a table in firebase. I can show them on a flatlist and put a corresponding like/reject button to each row. But I want to make it like tinder where one value (i.e profile) shows up and the user clicks an action (like/reject) and then the next one shows up. If I use flatlist, it will show all the values in a list. But I want it to be displayed one at a time. 
Any guidance on how can I achieve that?